# How to remove unwanted noise inbetween the digits of an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, contour

I am working in a project of optical character recognition using OpenCV. I have implemented ocr successfully on normal digits. But in Realtime scenario, i am getting problem with unwanted noise in between the digits. original image

i have converted to grayscale and applied threshold, then it comes like this

If i apply contour detection,then i will get those black blocks also.How can i eliminate that blocks between digits.I have no problem with OCR,I just want to remove that unwanted noise and to rotate the image.Thank you.

After rotating and removing black blobs from the image.This is the progress i achieved and how can I remove those blocks which are attached to the first digit due to shadow.

I am getting problem with the ocr. first and last 2 digits are not recognised          correctly.How to improve efficiency of ocr. After traininig the system with those digits where i am getting wrong with the sample digits from real time, I got the right results.

final ocr Image :

[image: final ocr image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the black bars without a priori knowledge of the geometry, I mean by pure blob analysis, is virtually impossible. It is also impossible to avoid that they come in contact with the digits, because of the strong shadows at the bottom.

I suggest to do your best to find those black bars, which are the places where the blobs have the greatest vertical extent. Maybe it is also possible to locate them in a profile obtained by taking the averages over the columns (six strong local minima).

[image]

When you have located these bars horizontally, you can erase them in the original image by filling white rectangles. You can also locate them vertically in their respective slices and use this information to perform deskewing, followed by erasure. You can also predict the position of the leftmost and rightmost voids.

This is the kind of result you can achieve:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank u sir for the reply and i got ur idea of detecting the blobs by vertical count of black pixels.but i can't remove the blobs perfectly.u can refer to the updated image in my post.first of all i implemented  1) binary threshold 2) getRotation2Dmatrix and wrapAffine functions for deskewing    3)i made a small code for detecting blobs  4) replaced those blobs with white spaces. I think the last step is not working fine.

Comment: if you are using opencv or matlab.please share ur implementation steps.

Comment: @PraveenGadiyaram: I did not, I used my own software. Your erasure stripes are too narrow, why don't you just enlarge them ?

Comment: sir i have enlarged the white overlapping blocks and updated the image in the post. and i removed small blobs by checking contourArea of all the blocks. But  I am unable to remove the noise from first digit which is coming by shadow.Thank u

Comment: sir do you have any idea of the font style of those digits

Comment: @PraveenGadiyaram I told you that the task is virtually impossible. Knowing the exact width and spacing of the digits you can more accurately erase. But finding the precise outlines at the bottom of the characters is hopeless.

Comment: @PraveenGadiyaram: there is no real need to know the font. Collect enough sample images (with good illumination) so that you see all ten digits.

Comment: sir once refer to "before ocr" and "after performing ocr" images in my post. I am using knn method for ocr. How to improve efficiency of ocr.???? I think we should  train the system with large data.

Comment: Sir do you have any collection of  images of different font styles and sizes of all ten digits  ?? beacuse right now i can't get the sample images. Thank you.

Comment: @PraveenGadiyaram The leftmost digit won't work because of poor framing.

Comment: @PraveenGadiyaram: no, it's your job to collect images of those tellers as found with the intended "customers".

Comment: sir i hav trained the system with those samples where i am getting wrong.Then i got the right result.once see the final ocr image in my post.Thank you very much sir, only because of u i made this project successful.